# How can I change some tree's radius and length in C# script in Unity3D?

Tags: unity, c#, tree

So, I have this little tree stem. It only has its initial node.

All I would like to do is make it grow in length and radius in Update(). How can I do that?

[image: Plant stem]

Comment: Please describe more about this tree model, as that information will affect the approach taken. Is this a procedurally generated mesh, or a 3D model that you imported?

Comment: is it going to be a train painting or single object? you can access polygons and vertices individually and edit them or jase change the scale in different axis https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-vertices.html